# Can't change element's height

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I'm trying to resize element by dragging (like [so](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Bek9L/1779/)). I wrote a simple directive (will handle ghostbar later):

```
@Directive({ selector: '[drag-resize]' })
export class DragResizeDirective {
    private dragging: boolean;

    constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer2) {
        renderer.listen('window', 'mouseup', (e) => {
            if (this.dragging) {
                el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; // Works fine.
                el.nativeElement.style.height = `${e.pageY + 2}px`; // Not so much.
                this.dragging = false;
            }
        });
    }

    @HostListener('mousedown') onMouseDown() {
        this.dragging = true;
    }
}
```

The problem is I can't change height of the element. Other styles work fine. I'm using Angular 4.0.3.

Computed attributes:

```
display: block;
height: 244.781px;
left: 0px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
position: absolute;
top: 655.422px;
width: 1793px;
```

*`renderer.setStyle()` doesn't work either.

** Element I'm trying to resize is a grid tile ([`md-grid-tile`](https://material.angular.io/components/component/grid-list) from Angular Material).

*** Directive works on other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit 2:

I've dug into the `md-grid-list` implementation. The row height is recalculated everytime that `ngAfterContentChecked` is triggered ([code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/52996773d13c2014ffdf013e3fe773e0d35915c8/src/lib/grid-list/grid-list.ts#L93)). This happens after every mouse event and is probably the reason why setting the height has no effect.

From the `md-grid-list` documentation I can see that you can also pass a `rowHeight` (e.g. 200px) input parameter to the `md-grid-list. This seems to be cleanest way to set the row height, but will scale all rows to the same size.

If this is not the effect you want to achieve, you can try setting the height in the [ngAfterViewChecked](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/AfterViewChecked-class.html) lifecycle hook.

---

Edit:

In case your code is trying to resize a `display: inline` element, you first have to apply a e.g. `display: inline-block` to it. Otherwise it will ignore the height value.

---

The `style.height` attribute expects numeric values to have a unit (e.g. `%`, `px`, `rem`, `em`, `vh`).

This should work:

```ts
el.nativeElement.style.height = `${e.pageX + 2}px`;
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, I'm sorry, I tried that, didn't work. Made a mistake in example code, updating.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another possible solution.

Comment: Element has display: block. Added computed attributes to the question.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another possible solution after checking the implementation.